# How to select latest date in MySql?

Tags: mysql, date

```
|id | cont_no| date     | 
+---+--------+----------+
|1  |    1   |01-02-2011|
|2  |    1   |21-02-2011|
|3  |    2   |08-01-2011|
|4  |    1   |25-01-2011|
```

date stored as ( dd-mm-yyyy) format , date column is varchar

now i want to select latest date

i tried like this but its not working

```
SELECT FROM table_name where cont_no='1' AND top(date)
```

this what the result i m expecting

```
|id | cont_no| date     | 
+---+--------+----------+
|1  |    1   |21-02-2011|
```

please some one help me

Comment: Is your date column of type `date` or `char()`

Comment: @Archios no jens query just selecting the first entered row ( id =1) not selecting latest date

Comment: @munna you have clear answers below still you couldn't get it's quirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is a char(x) you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name order by str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') desc limit 1
```

Comment: this query just returns 1st enter value , not selecting the latest date @jens

Comment: @MrMarlow Sorry my fault. Thanks for the informattion.

Comment: @Munna Try again please.

Comment: str_to_date already i corrected in my query SELECT * FROM cont_buying order by STR_TO_DATE('release_date','%d-%m-%y') desc limit 1

Comment: but this query not selecting latest date :-/

Comment: @Munna See my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91a71/1). The query works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name order by date desc limit 1

SELECT cont_no,max(date) FROM table_name group by cont_no
```

Comment: No this is not working query select High DATE ( eg : 25-01-2015 , 05-02-2015) then this query returns 25-01-2015 as top , latest date

Comment: what is your data type

Comment: try with the second query

Answer (score 0):

```
select         
    table_name.id,
    table_name.cont_no,    
    table_name.date  as date1     
from 
    table_name 
where 
    --  table_name.id = 2  and <---  if id will be needed to sort
    date(date1) <= DATE('21-02-2011')  -- if date sorting by date. notice the < though we want exact match date
    order by date1 desc     --  very important to bring required row to the first row!!
            limit 1  -- fetch only that row. be sure to use the right order i.e. desc or asc depending on usage
```

Hope it simplifies the need for complex joins etc just to select by column date